# How to look for a stronger electric motor for a DIY candy panner?

Tags: motors, torque

I'm an amateur working on a candy panner project, similar to [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6ZLn2XzrXs) but with a dedicated motor instead of an attached drill. After some experimentation, I have a working V1 that I successfully used to make some chocolate-covered peanuts as the test run.

The problem is that the motor I have is not powerful enough to turn the bowl with more than a small handful of peanuts at a time. On a cold start, the motor has trouble getting started (producing a clicking sound without spinning) and I need to give it a bit of a jumpstart after which it will eventually catch and start spinning on its own. Also, if I ever have to mix the contents or the bowl or scrape stuff off the side, it doesn't take much to cause the motor to slow/stop spinning and start clicking again. Not only does this greatly impede the batch size, but having an insufficient amount of peanuts makes it more likely that chocolate poured in will stick to the bowl instead of the peanuts, which is not only wasteful but it makes clumping much more likely.

I'm currently using [this electric motor I found on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J65VVFS), and I need to find a stronger replacement. The problem is that very few electric motors I can find on Amazon give their specs in terms I can recognize, so I'm not sure what to look for or how to compare it to what I have. All I know is that the one I have already says it's "high torque" and advertises 18W off of 0.11A (which already doesn't make much sense since it's running off of 110V and that math doesn't add up). From my experimentation, 60 RPM seems to be about the sweet spot for the size of bowl I have.

Is there something specific I should be looking for? Am I even using the right type of motor for this project? I assume the $150+ motors with a full hp or more are crazy overkill for this project. Also, while AC motors are more convenient, should I be considering DC motors as well?

Comment: So work out the load you need to overcome and then search for a motor. A lever of a known length and a spring balance will be close enough. DC motors like car wiper motors or car seat motors can be quite useful...

Comment: @SolarMike Okay, how do I do that?

Comment: "A lever of a known length and a spring balance will be close enough" the load can be calculated as a force multiplied by a distance. Just work in sensible units.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying to set up a lever, attach it to a spring scale, and then push down with my hand until the force feels about right? How do I equate the force of my hand's exertion with the force imparted by the bowl and contents of what amounts to a tumbling machine?